# How to create a completely device-compatible website

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Basically I want to create web pages for multiple devices (desktop, iphone, ipad, and other smart phones that have browsers on them).  I'm just beginning to learn css3 and learning css3 media queries is very confusing.


I read a few tutorials and the code below is what I came up with.  Could someone please let me know if I am doing this right, or if there are any corrections that should be made?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>

    <!-- META -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp" />
    <title>Home</title>

    <!-- CSS RESET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" media="all" />

    <!-- TARGET SMARTPHONES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-width: 321px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (max-width: 320px)" />

    <!-- IPADS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)" />

    <!-- DESKTOP & LAPTOPS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-width: 1224px)" />

    <!-- LARGE SCREEN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (min-width: 1824px)" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" />

  </head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would condense your conditional stylesheets into one.

Comment: Would condensing the stylesheets screw up the smart phones I'm targeting

Comment: No, just use the media query CSS syntax.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the syntax is.  What website would you recommend I visit to learn the media query syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be helpful to you, but I always like examples: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the following line to let the browser know how it should fit its content on the device's screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This article from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/) will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

Having so many style sheet links isn't good practice. For a small project website, you should need *at most* 2, but really you should only have one.  Design your one css style to adapt to the width of the page. As the page gets smaller, hide some block elements, once it gets small enough to be considered of phone width, then maybe have a mobile style sheet. Google responsive designs and you will get good examples. Take your mouse and just change the width of the screen to see how the pages react, use developer tools to see what elements get hidden or not, and then try to duplicate it yourself. You picked up a good time to learn, I have to say, web development is getting easier by the day with all the tools out there.

Comment: I usually add like 5 stylesheets at max.  one for the reset, one for layout, one for styling text and images, one for forms, and thats about it.  Is that too much for a small project if I am incorporating these type of stylesheets with the device-dedicated stylesheets?

Comment: why can't they be all in one stylesheet? checkout html5 boilerplate too for direction, use their stylesheet, it combines a lot of best practices for cross-browser support. You don't need a different style sheet for every different device, you just need different css rules applied to the page to when the screen width is changed

Comment: I usually organize the stylesheets into categories.  Gotcha, thanks this helped a lot